# Extract all obj files from a lib

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

How can I extract all .obj files from a .lib file? The only way I found is to extract one at once. Is there a way to automate it?

```
LIB.EXE /EXTRACT:member.obj Library.LIB
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could write a short program to do the calls for you using `system(...)`-Function.

That still leaves you with the problem of generating a list of member object files, though.

Answer (score 8):

This is the batch file that I ended up using with usage `extract.bat mylib.lib` or `extract.bat *.lib` even

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue

FOR %%F in (%1) DO (

    SET LIBFILE=%%F
    SHIFT

    @ECHO !LIBFILE!

    FOR /F %%O IN ('lib.exe /LIST !LIBFILE! /NOLOGO') DO (
        @SET OBJFILE=%%O
        @ECHO !OBJFILE!
        
        SET OBJPATH=%%~dO%%~pO
        SET OBJNAME=%%~nO

        IF NOT EXIST "!OBJPATH!" md !OBJPATH!

        IF EXIST "!OBJFILE!" ECHO !OBJFILE! exists, skipping...
        IF NOT EXIST "!OBJFILE!" lib.exe /NOLOGO !LIBFILE! "/EXTRACT:!OBJFILE!" "/OUT:!OBJFILE!"
    )
)
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked like a charm!

Comment: The original OBJPATH in my LIBFILE was mapped to a "G:" drive that did not exist on my system. So when it tried to output the obj file to the original path, it complained of invalid location. So I did the following:

SET OBJNAME=%%~nxO
and 
lib.exe /NOLOGO !LIBFILE! "/EXTRACT:!OBJFILE!" "/OUT:!OBJNAME!"

This would put all objs in the same folder and loose directory structure, but that was fine with my usage.

Comment: This might be the best solution. But besides this there is another way. The .lib file is an archive this can be extracted with 7z or other archive tool.